# SQLiteOpenHelper instance in multiple Activities and Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, sqliteopenhelper

**tl;dr:** What's the best way of handling instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class in an app with multiple `Activities` and `Fragments`? Should I have only one instance in the whole app and pass it between individual `Activities`, or can I create a new instance for every `Activity` and `Fragment`?

**(Much) more detailed question:** I'm having problems understanding how should I handle `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance in my app. I have a `DBHelper` (which extends the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class) and it's implemented as a singleton. Then I have one `Activity` with multiple `Fragments` inside (user switches between the `Fragments` by using a navigation drawer), and then I have some other `Activities` without any `Fragments` inside them. I read here many answers and comments here on SO that I should always have only one `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance, but these answers only gave examples with a single `Activity`. What those answers actually only said was that the `SQLiteOpenHelper` should be a singleton - which it already is in my app. But I couldn't find any info anywhere on how should I handle the `SQLiteOpenHelper` object in a bit more complex app.

I can think of three possible ways of dealing with the situation, and would really appreciate your input and guidance, as this is something that is not very well documented, in my opinion.

**Possibility #1:** Keeping only one instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` and passing it between all `Activities` and `Fragments` in my app. For example, I would instantiate it in the first `Activity` that starts when the user launches the app and then I'd pass the instance to all other `Activities` and `Fragments` that need access to the database. That means that I would have only one instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` across the whole app.

**Possibility #2:** Creating a new instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` in every `Activity` that needs it. `Activities` are destroyed when a new one is started anyways, therefore the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance from the old `Activity` should be garbage-collected, and so this seems like it should work. And the `Fragments` inside one of my `Activities` would simply get the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance from their "parent" `Activity` (using an interface pattern, I guess). I read that when I keep only one instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` active at a time, there's not any problem with DB syncing. Also the database apparently never has to be closed with the singleton pattern.

**Possibility #3:** Creating a new instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` in every `Activity` and `Fragment` that needs it. This is how I first started writing my app, but now I'm on doubts - I have an instance of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` in the `Activity` that has some `Fragments` in it, and I have another instance of the database helper in the currently displayed `Fragment`. Therefore I have two active connections to the database at a time - one in the `Fragment` and one in its parent `Activity`.

I'm asking because I just enabled strict mode in my app, and now I'm getting crashes. Specifically:

```
StrictMode: Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed.
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

The weird thing is that the stack trace is pointing me to a line where I'm instantiating a Cursor and reading data from the database (the 5th line of the code):

```
public List<Long> getDrinkIdsByDayMinute(int dayOfWeek, int minuteOfDay) {
    List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // The stack trace points to the following line:
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + DRINK_LOG_COLUMN_DRINK_ID + ", COUNT("
                    + DRINK_LOG_COLUMN_DRINK_ID + ") FROM " + DRINK_LOG_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                    + DRINK_LOG_COLUMN_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = ? AND "
                    + DRINK_LOG_COLUMN_MINUTE_OF_DAY + " BETWEEN ? AND ? AND "
                    + DRINK_LOG_COLUMN_DELETED + " = ? GROUP BY " + DRINK_LOG_COLUMN_DRINK_ID
                    + " ORDER BY 2 DESC",
            new String[]{Integer.toString(dayOfWeek), Integer.toString(minuteOfDay - 30),
                    Integer.toString(minuteOfDay + 30), Integer.toString(0)});
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        result.add(cursor.getLong(0));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

In the `DBHelper` class I have multiple methods for getting data from the database (and to write/update data as well), and in every single one of those methods I'm closing the `Cursor` with the data (because that's apparently the right thing to do to prevent memory leaks). But at the same time, in every single one of those methods I'm also calling `getReadableDatabase()` (or `getWriteableDatabase()`) methods, performing some queries on the database object, and then I'm NOT closing it (I read some mixed opinions on closing `SQLiteDatabase` objects). I actually tried to go ahead and close the `SQLiteDatabase` at the end of every method in my `DBHelper` class, but that resulted a crash with the same error in a different part of the code.

Is any of the possibilities (#1 - #3) a good one? Or should I think of some other way of dealing with the `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance? And, additional question, since I'm closing the `Cursor` in every single method in my `DBHelper` class, should I also close the `SQLiteDatabase` object? And isn't my way of handling the `SQLiteDatabase` object wrong? Shouldn't I perhaps create a member variable with the `SQLiteDatabase` object when I'm instantiating the `DBHelper` class, and then use only this one instead of instantiating it in every method?

Comment: I'm not really a database expert, so l won't post an answer. But it seems to me that all three approaches are basically OK *if implemented correctly*. The crash you mentioned may be due to using the Activity/ the Fragment's Context when instantiating the SQLiteOpenHelper - at least this was the case for one of my apps. The crashes stopped after I started using the Application Context for the SQLiteOpenHelper.